# Can't access page-wide javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm fetching a JSON response and with that response, I have two values:

1. Air shipment cost.
2. Land shipment cost.

I want to save those two values somewhere in the client so that when a user chooses either 1 radio button or the other, I add that value to another element on the page.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var landCost;
        var airCost;

$("#ddlCiudad").change(function () {
    var idCity = $("#ddlCiudad").val();
    $.getJSON("/ProductCheckout/GetPriceForLocation", { cityId: idCity, productId: idProduct, type: "land" },
        function (cityData) {
            console.log("Recieved json data."); //This part works. It outputs.

            var data = $.parseJSON(cityData);
            console.log("Parse JSON response."); //This part works. It outputs.

            landCost = data.LandCost;
            console.log("Assigned value of LandCost"); //FAILS HERE. nothing is shown. not even an error.
            airCost = data.AirCost;
            console.log("Assigned value of AirCost");

            alert(landCost);
            console.log("Alerted land!");
            alert(airCost);
            console.log("Alerted air!");
        }
    );
});
```

So what do you suggest? I need to have the values of this JSON response, available for usage on that page, if I declare the variable inside the change() event, it'll be out of scope.

```
{"DaysToShip":" TER = 48 Hrs / AER = 24 Hrs","LandCost":"25,00","AirCost":""}
```

Comment: A quick fix would be to move the `landCost` and `airCost` declarations outside of document ready, so they'll be global.

Comment: I don't see why it would fail where you marked.  If you put a `console.log(data)` after `parseJSON`, do you get the object you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
landCost = cityData.LandCost;
```

Comment: Solved my problem. :) Curious though, if I can access JSON values like this, why would I need the parseJSON method?

Comment: I take it back, I guess the OP wasn't posting the actual layout. @Sergio, if you call $.getJSON then jquery automatically parses it and returns an object/array you can use immediately.

Comment: From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ 'As of jQuery 1.5, the success callback function receives a "jqXHR" object' so my guess is that the parseJSON method is unnecessary

Comment: You don't need to call $.parseJSON() as it has already been parsed for you into a javascript object.

Answer (score 0):

If you really must use global variables, you can attach them directly to the window object.

```
window.airCost = cityData.AirCost;
```

Really though you want to have the json request and the 'radio button' handling in the same scope, so that you're not polluting the global namespace at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `$.parseJSON()` is returning `null` because the data passed to your callback has already been parsed to JSON.

```
var json = {LandCost:3, AirCost:5},
    results = $.parseJSON(json);

console.log(results); // results == null
```

Answer (score -1):

IF you want to globally declare your variables, either put them outside the jQuery closure (`$(document).ready(function () {...});`), or don't use `var` to declare them. If you don't use the `var` keyword the variable will default to a global.

Here is a jsfiddle of setting global variables without using the `var` keyword: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/JWtbV/

Comment: Never suggest to people not to use `var`. Globals are bad, but creating them implicitly like that is an order of magnitude worse.

Comment: After running some performance tests it is slower (which is no shocker) however more like 20% slower, not 100% or worse.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using jQuery's [$.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function to attached the values directly to the body element in the DOM and accessing it from there?

```
// Set Values
$('body').data('landCost', data.LandCost);
$('body').data('airCost', data.AirCost);

// Retrieve Values //
console.log($('body').data('landCost');
console.log($('body').data('airCost');
```

Hope it helps.